# How can I determine what "token" is causing an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a page that uses jQuery to show and hide the content on the page. I've got the code working, but when it completes in the console of the browser it errors:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

However I can't see what invalid or unexpected token it is injecting into the code.

I've run the code through a checker and there isn't anything wrong with the code, just hoping that someone would be able to shed some light on a piece that I should be using to not have these issues. I've also created a fiddle, to run and check for these errors, just to make sure it's not due to the current placement of the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".featuresList").on("click", ".alert-cerberus", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".alert-cerberus").removeClass("active");
        $(".featuresContent").removeClass("show");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('onclick')).addClass("show");
    });
});
```

Here is a js fiddle that I have set up to duplicate this: https://jsfiddle.net/jgilbertdesign/2j3xzbad/14/#&togetherjs=GxhzJJBHus

The code should make the selection panel that is chosen show a different color and have the content appear on the page. Similar to the hide/show function that is a base of jQuery but without having to build out multiple lines of code to back that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Token" just refers to a thing, be it a string or a variable or whatever. In this case, clicking on the error directs you to this line in your markup:

```
<div class="..." role="alert" onclick="#powerfulFTP">
```

While it's not explicitly clear what the problem is, it's that the `onclick` attribute expects an expression, not a string. It's attempting to evaluate the string as an expression, which results in the error.

You should probably be passing your string in a data attribute:

```
data-whatever="#powerfulFTP"
```

Then grab it:

```
$( $(this).data('whatever') ).addClass('show');
```

(`whatever` should be a semantic term for the thing itself, maybe `data-parentId`.)

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dvqe4sgu/)**

Also, you shouldn't need `preventDefault` here since you're not working with an anchor.

Unsolicited protips:

- Note the `document.ready` shorthand in my demo. Saves some typing.
- Using single quotes for JS and double for HTML saves some escaping headaches.

Comment: Yes but it adds that error to every line as you click on other pieces. So its stating that something is being added everytime you click on one of the alerts that initiates the code.

Comment: No, it's attempting to evaluate the expression, which isn't an expression.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that the `onclick=` kicks in *before* the jquery delegated event handler.

So the browser sees `onclick='#powerfulFtp'` and attempts to evaluate it, giving an error.

Change `<div onclick='#abc'>` to `<div data-onclick='#abc'>` and the event from

```
$($(this).attr('onclick')).addClass("show");
```

to

```
$($(this).data('onclick')).addClass("show");
```

and it will work fine.